# Cocos2d: TileMap : how to minimize memory usage of Tilemap

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using CCTMXTiledMap for extracting properties of objects at different positions in my Layer's Init function. I store these positions in a separate array and do not need TileMap anymore.

Here is the code:

```
-(void) init{
...
CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"TileMap2.tmx"];
CCTMXLayer *tmxLayer= [tileMap layerNamed:@"Layer1"]; 
for(int i=0;i<9999;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            int gid = [tmxLayer tileGIDAt:ccp(i,j)];
            properties = [tileMap propertiesForGID:gid];
            _obstacles[m].type = CUBE_; m++;
        }
     }
...
}
```

After Init method TileMap gets released.

**Problem:** Because Tilemap is very big (9999x20) it takes a lot of memory. So the peak memory goes high to 18MB while the for loop is running.

Is there any other method by which I can extract the properties at different positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tile consumes between (roughly) 100 Bytes and 500 Bytes of memory. The latter is the case if cocos2d has to create a CCSprite for the tile, for example if you set any CCSprite property such as scale, color, or run an action on the tile.

9999x20 means you have close to 200,000 tiles. Times 100 Bytes gives around 19 MB. So you're just getting the expected results.

If you want to reduce the memory usage you'll have to use a different implementation ([HKTMXTileMap](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17945) is a contender) or roll your own.

Comment: Solved..I am breaking my long tilemap into 3 small tilemaps.